# connect to SQL server on Parallel VM from R

Tags: sql, sql-server, r, odbc, virtual-machine

I have my Rstudio installed on Mac, and SQL server Management studio in Parallel VM. now, I am trying to connect R with SQL server using RODBC package. I think I have the sql server driver installed on my computer. i am not familiar with database. below are what I did:

1. set up User DSN 'orca4' in Parallel VM (Windows 7), driver name 'SQl Server Native Client 11.0' (it was tested successfully).
2. run R odbcConnect('orca4'), it gave me message '[iODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified. Driver could not be loaded'
3. then I tried cn <- odbcDriverConnect(connection="Driver={SQL Server 
   Native Client 11.0};server='1244gfgfgr';database='NewHome';
   trusted_connection=yes;"). i got similar message
   ERROR: state IM003, code -1988948897, message [iODBC][Driver Manager]Specified driver could not be loaded

Could anyone let me know what is the problem here?

Comment: According to this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240374/connect-to-sqlserver-running-in-a-parallels-vm), you may need to set up remote connections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the client that needs the DSN, not the server.  You want to create a DSN on your Mac that R can access.  I'm not familiar with how to do this on OSX, but looks like this link might help:

http://www.actualtech.com/readme.php

Comment: thanks, I downloaded their mac OSX driver and ODBC manager, the connection works just fine.