# How to test connection to MS SQL server running on Parallels on Mac OS?

Tags: sql-server, macos, parallels

I am using visual studio for Mac and I have my sql server instance running on windows 10 using parallels. I enabled port 1433 in the inbound rules in the firewall and enabled the browser agent in my Sql config. as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240374/connect-to-sqlserver-running-in-a-parallels-vm). I am running my app using this connection string

```
"DefaultConnection": "Server=smb://10.211.55.4/WINDOWS10PRO;Database=aspnet-Testapp-53bc9b9d-9d6a-45d4-8429-2a2761773502;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
```

but I am getting `SqlException`

> SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred
>   while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not
>   found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct
>   and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
>   (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 25 - Connection string is
>   not valid)

How can I test my connection to the database using Mac OS ?

Comment: Turn-OFF The firewall and Check whether it's working proper or not.Then do the ODBC and Check On Which Port SQL is running

Comment: @AlfaizAhmed, 1433, how to check using Mac OS?

Comment: @MatSnow, Not a duplicate, I implemented the same solution and is not working

Comment: first Close The Fire wall on Your Server Machine And Run the Link from MAC If it's working then Try to give new port for Port 85 IN Inbound Outbound rule .

Comment: You can confirm the connection outside of code from the command line. you can use telnet with ;  telnet ip# port#