# How to connect to SQL Server Express using parallels desktop

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, parallels

How can I input the correct connection string to the `appsetting.json` file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should connect using your internal network IP and specify it's a tcp connection.

Let's say your IP is: 192.168.0.5 and SQL server is running on port 1433 and it's a named instance:

`Server=tcp:192.168.0.5,1433\YourInstanceName;Database=YourDbName;User Id=YourUsername;Password=YourPassword;`

If you don't have a named instance:

`Server=tcp:192.168.0.5,1433;Database=YourDbName;User Id=YourUsername;Password=YourPassword;`

Make sure to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240374/connect-to-sqlserver-running-in-a-parallels-vm) thread as you need to execute some steps for SQL server to be accessible.